# Syntax error in foreach line

Tags: php

Here is the total codes Trying separate ways but cant do it.

```
$sql_select_cats_list = $db->query("SELECT category_id, items_counter, hover_title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE parent_id=0 AND hidden=0 AND user_id=0 AND enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC");


$cats = array();
while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_select_cats_list)) {
    $cats[$row['category_id']] = $row;
}
$cat_ids = implode(', ', array_keys($cats));


$sql_select_subcats_list = $db->query("SELECT sub.category_id, sub.items_counter, sub.hover_title, parent.order_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories sub LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "categories parent ON (parent.category_id=sub.parent_id) WHERE parent.category_id IN (" . $cat_ids . ") AND sub.hidden=0 AND sub.user_id=0 AND sub.enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY parent.order_id ASC, sub.order_id ASC, sub.name ASC");


while($row=$db->fetch_array($sql_select_subcats_list)) {
    if(!isset($subs[$row['parent_id']])) {
        $subs[$row['parent_id']] = array();
    }
    $subs[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
}


$template->set('cats_list', $cats);
$template->set('subs_list', $subs);


$category_box_content = $template->process('header_categories_box.tpl.php');
$template->set('category_box_content', $category_box_content);
```

I am trying to list categories and sub categories with this code:

```
 <?php
    foreach($cats as $parent_id => $cats_header_details) {
       $category_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']], 'parent_id' => $cats_header_details['category_id']));


       // subcategory links:
       if(isset($subs_list[$parent_id])) {
        foreach($subs_list[$parent_id]) as $sub) { 
            // do something with your subcategory


        }
       }
    ?>   




 <li><a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal;" href="<?=$category_link;?>" 
                <?=((!empty($cats_header_details['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $cats_header_details['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?> alt="">


<img src="themes/<?=$setts['default_theme'];?>/img/arrow.gif" border="0" hspace="4"><?=$category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']];?>         


<?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ? (($cats_header_details['items_counter']) ? '(<strong>' . $cats_header_details['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' : '') : '');?></a>   </li>   <? 
            } 
            ?>
```

I get this Warning: Think foreach is returning empty ! cant find the way how to solve it.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\site\themes\temamiz\templates\categories_box.tpl.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($subs_list[$parent_id]) as $sub) {  
foreach($subs_list[$parent_id] as $sub) {
```

after `$subs_list[$parent_id]` delete ")"

Comment: Thanks, now I get another error:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\site\themes\temamiz\templates\categories_box.tpl.php on line 14`

Here is the total code :

`<?php
foreach($cats as $parent_id => $cats_header_details) {
$category_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']], 'parent_id' => $cats_header_details['category_id'])); 
// subcategory links:
   if(isset($subs_list[$parent_id])) {
    foreach($subs_list[$parent_id] as $sub) {
    }
   }
?>`

Comment: if you mean categories ? yes it is null,  I will add all of the code and you can check please.